# ng star rating is not working while adding totalstars options

Tags: angular

i am using ng-starrating https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-starrating library in my angular project. it works when i didn't specify the totalstars option like this.

```
<star-rating value="{{rate}}" checkedcolor="#000000" uncheckedcolor="#ffffff">
```

`

but doesn't works if i add totalstars option to this.

```
<star-rating value="{{rate}}" checkedcolor="#000000" uncheckedcolor="#ffffff"
totalstars="{{rate}}">
```

it is not showing the stars at all after i include this option.

Comment: As per my knowledge totalstars should be greaterthan equal to value. Here you set both same variable. Try giving 5 or 10 as value and check.

Comment: but i need to display only the stars which are enabled/checked for the same reason i am specifying the same variable. (if 2 stars i need to show 2 stars).

Comment: @venkateshkarthick The issue is with the package. I have checked it. Please report a bug for the same.

Comment: Sir I am also using same package but in my case start not showing in html can you tell me sir what's the issue?

Answer (score 5):

If you set it as:

```
totalstars='5'
```

then it won't work.

Change it to:

```
[totalstars]='5'
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example

your error

```
checkedcolor="#000000" uncheckedcolor="#ffffff"
```

solution

```
checkedcolor="red" uncheckedcolor="black"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-star-rating-demo-kfgkqt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        ng-starrating demo
    </h1>
    <star-rating value="5" totalstars={{totalstar}} checkedcolor="red" uncheckedcolor="black" size="24px"
        readonly="false" (rate)="onRate($event)"></star-rating>
</div>
```

in your .ts

```
totalstar = 10;
```

Comment: It is not because of " " marks i have tried that also.it is working in the jsfiddle but not in the angular project. the question is more specific to should i do (import) something in order make it(totalstars option) work.

Comment: i found exact cause it is  `checkedcolor="red"` and `uncheckedcolor="black" `

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use latest version of ng-starrating. This issue is fixed.

Comment: You can add this as comment, If you have a detailed answer which can help people in future then you can elaborate it and post it as answer :)